Get an AWS FIFO SQS queue to output multiple messages as one event
I have a FIFO SQS queue connecting two Lambda functions. Each SQS message is sent by the first Lambda function and consumed by the second Lambda function. If multiple SQS messages are sent within a 5 second period, I'd like to combine them into one event, so that the second Lambda function can process them all the same time.
How can I do this?

Side-question: Can I ask... Why are you connecting two Lambda functions via an SQS queue? Normally, queues are used to buffer messages between processes, but Lambda functions can scale to huge volumes. There should normally be no need to put a buffer between them. Is it due to the need to process messages in a specific order? Is the second function configured to only process one message at a time?

AWS Batch can work with SQS via a Lambda.

Amazon SQS can send a batch of up to 10 messages to an AWS Lambda function. Your Lambda function should always loop through the Records list, processing every message (unless you have configured the function for a Batch Size of 1).
From Using Lambda with Amazon SQS - AWS Lambda:

With Amazon SQS event source mappings, Lambda polls the queue and invokes your function synchronously with an event. Each event can contain a batch of multiple messages from the queue. Lambda receives these events one batch at a time, and invokes your function once for each batch. When your function successfully processes a batch, Lambda deletes its messages from the queue.
...
By default, Lambda polls up to 10 messages in your queue at once and sends that batch to your function. To avoid invoking the function with a small number of records, you can configure the event source to buffer records for up to 5 minutes by configuring a batch window. Before invoking the function, Lambda continues to poll messages from the standard queue until the batch window expires, the invocation payload size quota is reached, or the configured maximum batch size is reached.
If you're using a batch window and your SQS queue contains very low traffic, Lambda might wait for up to 20 seconds before invoking your function. This is true even if you set a batch window lower than 20 seconds.

So, you should configure the batch window of the second Lambda function to be 5 seconds. That should batch messages together before invoking the second Lambda function.
